# Como inserir contador regressivo em tabela? HTML e Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Como faço para colocar o contador regressivo do lado de cada nome que é inserido na tabela? Sendo que o contador regressivo deve começar dos 20 min a cada nome inserido

```
<head>


<script type="text/javascript">
function startTimer(duration, display) {
var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
setInterval(function () {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10); 
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
        timer = 0;
    }

}, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
var fiveMinutes = 60 * 20,
display = document.querySelector('#time');
startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
};



var d = document;
function processar(idTabela){

 var newRow = d.createElement('tr');
 newRow.insertCell(0).innerHTML = d.getElementsByName('user')[0].value;
 newRow.insertCell(1).appendChild(time);
 d.getElementById(idTabela).appendChild(newRow);
 return false;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<br>

<font size="6">  
<table border='1' width='250' height='250' > 


<tbody id="myTable"> </tbody></font>
```

```
<font size="4" >Nome:   <input type="text" name="user" >


<input type="submit" value="Confirmar"> 

<div id="time"></div>

</font>

</form>

</body>
```

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse plugin: https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue solução para o seu problema: https://jsfiddle.net/tnym8dLe/

Comment: VOCÊ É UM GÊNIO <3

Comment: Amigo, sabe dizer como exportar essa tabela para o excel ? Ou salva-la em algum canto?